# Different date in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

Mongo's Date is differ from system and nodeJS date settings. How can I fix that?

**mongo:**

```
> new Date()
ISODate("2014-06-23T08:53:45.585Z")
> exit
bye
```

**Debian system:**

```
root@vm85820:/var/node/mrandom.com# date

Mon Jun 23 12:54:14 MSK 2014
```

**node:**

```
root@vm85820:/var/node/mrandom.com# node
> new Date()
Mon Jun 23 2014 12:54:24 GMT+0400 (MSK)
```

Comment: Yes. One seralizes ISO (UTC) and the other is in your local time. What actually is your question? Why is this a problem?

Comment: It seems like your possible concern here is that using `new Date()` in your node application will be different to the mongo shell. It will not be so. The underlying driver to your application will serialize to UTC time just as is returned from the shell invocation. Try it, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not different. The MongoDB time is in UTC, the other one in MSK timezone (+4 hours).

Answer (score 0):

The dates are the same, but MongoDB shell displays the time in UTC format (using ISODate wrapper). In MongoDB shell, when you use `new Date()` it will create a new Date object using ISODate wrapper, but if you use just `Date()` it will return current date as string.

```
> Date()
Mon Jun 23 2014 11:08:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

You can also convert the `Date` object to string using `toTimeString` method:

```
> new Date().toTimeString()
11:08:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Internally, MongoDB stores `Date` objects as a 64 bit integers that represent the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.